HP Omen laptop: identify 2 tiny cables
I had to replace the fans in my HP Omen laptop. It went well. Before I put the case back together I've noticed two small wires with tiny connectors (yellow arrows) that aren't connected to anything. One of them has "1" printed on it. I don't recall disconnecting them when disassembling the laptop, so it seems that they were either not plugged into anything, or plugged very lightly. They look like tiny gold antenna connectors. The closest thing that I can see that one of them could be plugged "onto" is a tiny prong (green arrow). Does anyone know what these wires/connectors are and whether I should "plug" one of them onto the tiny prong?


They are u.fl connectors. Depending on the model of the WLAN card to the right of you picture they would connect to one or both of the antenna ports. They may be used for Wifi or bluetooth depending on what options your laptop has

This ^^^ and "1" should be "main" and the other "aux". No, it has nothing to do with green arrow prong. Look for the connectors on the WLAN card near the wires.

The green arrow is a nut….

OK, thank you. Next time I open the laptop, I'll check if there are any connectors on the WLAN card to the right. If there aren't any, then I'll just leave the 2 connectors unconnected.

There certainly are, those are for the antennae built inside the screen's bezel. Honestly, if you have to ask this you shouldn't be doing it. Any decent and honest computer shop would've done it for ~€50 in most parts of Europe. Suggestion: Next time take a photo before start disassembling stuff. This time it DIDN'T go well, obviously, but it was inconsequential (at first glance); next time there might be consequences far more expensive than what you saved by DIY'ing.
